# HTML line break tags aren't working properly

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

So I'm working on a Instagram gallery for my website, and initially I was having issues with getting the images to "pop-out" on hover without being cut-off (the image was being cropped instead of enlarging) which I have since figured out.

Now I have a new issue. In-between the Instagram feed and a homemade picture carousel, I have some text titles dividing the two, so the format is:

**Instagram Feed (title)**

*(actual picture feed)*

line break `<br>`

**Gallery (title)**

*(actual carrousel)*

line break `<br>`

For some reason, the line breaks I put in before the **Gallery Title** aren't working now. The issue seems to be with the css for my Instagram feed.
I literally have to put like 20 of them `<br>` for the gallery title to move down. What I have noticed is that when I switch from "inline" to "block" on my

```
#instagram-feed1 {
  display: inline;
}
```

class the breaks work, but then my images get cropped on hover again.

Not sure what the issue is. See my html markup and CSS below.

// HTML

```
    <div class="div3">
      <div class="card-header headers">
        <h2>Pictures</h2>
      </div>

    <br>

      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-subtitle">
          <h3>On Instagram <img style="width: 40px;" src="./Images/instagram_logo.png" alt="instagram logo"></h3>
        </div>
        <div id="instagram-feed1" class="instagram_feed"></div>

        <br>

      <div class="card-subtitle">
        <h3>Gallery <img style="width: 40px;" src="./Images/gallery-icon.png" alt="gallery icon"></h3>
      </div>

      <div id="gallery">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3" aria-label="Slide 4"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="4" aria-label="Slide 5"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="5" aria-label="Slide 6"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="6" aria-label="Slide 7"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="./Images/Feudale-3.png" class="gallery-image" alt="FEUDALE LOGO">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./Images/DAVE.jpg" class="gallery-image" alt="PHOTO OF DAVE">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./Images/BRY.jpg" class="gallery-image" alt="PHOTO OF BRY">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./Images/MIKE.jpg" class="gallery-image" alt="PHOTO OF MIKE">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./Images/EPK1.jpg" class="gallery-image" alt="PHOTO OF BAND">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./Images/EPK2.jpg" class="gallery-image" alt="PHOTO OF BAND">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="./Images/FEUDALE_edit2.png" class="gallery-image" alt="PHOTO OF BAND">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

// CSS

```css
    /* INSTAGRAM FEED */
  
    .instagram_feed {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #instagram-feed1 {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .instagram_feed .instagram_new {
      width:25%;
      float:left;
      padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -o-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .instagram_feed img.insta-image {
      position: absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      object-fit: cover;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
      -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
      -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
      -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
      -o-transition:all 0.3s ease0s;
    }
      
    .instagram_feed .insta-link {
      position:relative;
      display:block;
      background:#232323;
      padding-top:100%;
      /* margin-top: 5%;
      margin-bottom: 5%;
      margin-left: 5%;
      margin-right: 5%; */
    }
    
    .instagram_feed .insta-link:hover .insta-image {
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2,2);
      opacity: 100;
      background-color: rgb(41,47,51, .0);
      position: absolute;
      object-fit:contain;
      display: inline;
      z-index:999;
      visibility: visible;
      transition-property: all;
      -webkit-transition-property: all;
       -moz-transition-property: all;
       -o-transition-property: all;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      transition-timing-function: ease;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
      -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
      -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
    }
```